# In Dafny, given a finite map, can I get its domain?

Tags: dafny

I'm passed a finite map, m. Is there a way to compute its domain? Something like m.Domain, dom(m), etc. The reference manual doesn't say that there is such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `m.Keys` for that.

Unfortunately, this change is relatively recent, and the reference manual is out of date in this respect.

The `Keys` option is briefly mentioned in the [release notes to version 1.9.9](https://github.com/Microsoft/dafny/releases/tag/v1.9.9).